# Raise ValidationError from pre_save receiver function?

Tags: django, forms, model, signals

I'd like to inform the user if something fails during processing of the data in `instance` in my `pre_save` receiver function.

Is it possible to raise a custom `ValidationError` from the receiver function? If not, how would I go about implementing something like this?

Answer (score 9):

You can raise whatever exception you want within the `pre_save` listener function, it will propagate to your `save()` call and prevent it from suceeding.

It will bubble up to where you call `save()`, from here, you can catch it (try/except…) and notify the user.

Comment: What if it's an admin form on which we dont access code ? Is there a way to just throw an exception and it gets nicely rendered as a form error in the admin ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should either use Model.clean() method (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean) or form clean http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method.

Comment: But how can I do that from within the pre_save method?